# AngularJS URL parameters to controller in array form

Tags: angularjs, url, url-parameters

I would like to have an URL such as

```
/1234?labels=label1,label2,label3
```

I get `1234` by using routeParams. I know I could use `$location.search().labels` to get `label1, label2, label3`. However, I would like to retrieve an array, `[label1, label2, label3]`. There could be more labels than 3 passed in.

```
app.config(function (toastrConfig, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    angular.extend(toastrConfig, {
        allowHtml: true,
        timeOut: 3000,
        positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
        preventDuplicates: true,
        progressBar: true
    });

    $routeProvider
    .when('/:type/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html'
    })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just decided to you `$location.search().labels.split(',')` and it works!